# How to properly specify theme variables in extjs?

Tags: css, extjs, sass, styles

I have been trying to learn styling in extjs, but I cannot figure out how it works. In a very simple example, I would like to apply some styles to panel header:

**app.js**

```
Ext.application({
    name: 'Fiddle',

    launch: function () {
        Ext.create('Ext.panel.Panel', {
            title: 'MyPanel',
            cls: 'title',
            renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
            items: [{
                xtype: 'button',
                text: 'myButton'
            }, {
                html: 'Hello World!!!',
            }]

        })
    }
});
```

So, according to [documentation](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.2.0/classic/Ext.panel.Panel.html#css_var-S-$panel-body-font-weight) I managed to change header `background-color` with the following css file:

**app.css**

```
.title .x-panel-header {
    background-color: pink;
    color: red;      /* this doesn't work */
    font-size: 22px; /* this doesn't work */  
}
```

The problem is that some theme variables aren't applied correctly - for example, text color or font-size, although these variables are specified according to documentation for panel header. What am I missing?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Almost all ExtJS components have a `style` or `cls` property.
Manually overriding the extjs css classes should be the last resort.

In your case you should be looking at these components:

[Ext.panel.Header](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.2.0/classic/Ext.panel.Header.html)

[Ext.panel.Title](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.2.0/classic/Ext.panel.Title.html)

The [panel](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.2.0/classic/Ext.panel.Panel.html) component should have a [header](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.2.0/classic/Ext.panel.Panel.html#cfg-header) `config` and the header component should have a [title](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.2.0/classic/Ext.panel.Header.html#cfg-title) `config` to customize each part.

Here is working example: [Sencha fiddle example](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/3b9m)

**For the sass variables you mentioned**

They are used to customize ExtJS Themes. So if you want to make your own theme with let's say triton as base you can use these variables to create your own theme. This is quite useful if you want to make overrides for the whole theme (e.g. the background color of all Ext.panel.Panel components)

I'd recommend you to read this guide for more information on this subject: [Theming guide](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.2.0/guides/core_concepts/theming.html)

---

Comment: Do you have an idea how to apply the css border rule for the [Ext.panel.Panel](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.6.0/classic/Ext.panel.Panel.html)? I'm trying with             `bodyStyle: {border: '55x solid red',}` but get no positive results.

Comment: Do you have something like this in mind? https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/3k5t

Comment: Exactly like this. Thank you.